# php javascript json parse escape characters

Tags: php, javascript, json, mustache

I currently have a webpage that need to use javascript to parse variables from php.
I do things like this:

```
data.notices = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($notices) ?>');
```

However, when there is single or double quotes in the $notices variable, javascript console return errors.

How can I get the variables correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn`t return error

```
<?
$notices = array('sad'=>'asd as" asd', 'asd"sdf '=>'asdasd" \' asd ads');
?>
<script>
data = new Object();
data.notices = JSON.parse('<?php echo addslashes(json_encode($notices)) ?>');
</script>
```

Comment: [{"content":"\\'\\'hello"}] this return errors. I think when I write a single quote in database, I found in mssql server it is stored as \'. When I get the variable from database to $notices, it becomes "\\'\\'hello" again.

Comment: @user985874 I have no error when use `$notices = array('content'=>"\\'\\'hello");`

Answer (score 1):

`$a='b'` will be converted to `"b"`(note the quotation mark) by `json_encode`

just write `JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($notices) ?>);`(remove `'`) will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it is the problem caused by the fact that I did not escape the characters before inserting to database.

Answer (score 0):

You are one extra operation. If you want message as javascript variable you can directly get like

```
data.notices = <?php echo json_encode($notices) ?>;
// and access like this
// data.notices[0] or data.notices['alert']
```